# AngularJS How to test expecting any parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I use AngularJS and Jasmine Karma unit  tests. Here I don't want to test my http call with the exact timestamp(which leads to failure time to time), but want to match it with whatever parameter is sent as a "stamp" value;

```
$httpBackend.expectGET(path/company?stamp='+new Date().getTime()).respond(200);
```

Couldn't find a way to do it!

Comment: I hope this doesn't sound too stupid since I don't know the full context of your problem, but since this is for testing purposes, just set the dummy timestamp to some fixed integer? Then the `expectGET` can be done quite easily

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a spy on the Date `getTime` method of the `Date` prototype and have it return a value that you can expect.

```
var timestamp = 1234;
spyOn(Date.prototype, 'getTime').andReturn(timestamp);
$httpBackend.expectGET('path/company?stamp='+timestamp).respond(200);
```

Now you can control the time and get a value that you can check for.